# Webdriver manager not launching chrome browser 'Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist' even with newest versions

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Chrome version is newest release: Version 116.0.5845.188

I have updated to the newest version of selenium:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.12.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I have updated to the newest version of webdriver manager:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
  <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
  <version>5.5.3</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

The error message I get is:

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist 
Host info: host: 'E0910774', ip: '10.255.84.61'
Build info: version: '4.12.1', revision: '8e34639b11'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.8.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```